# Summing column after multiple Union and Join operations

Tags: mysql, database, join, union

I am looking to sum the total of a column based on a player belonging to a certain team. I have a player table and a team table. Currently, I have no problem except that for some reason it will not sum the very last piece of my query. Here is an example of my code:

```
Select SUM(points)
from (select points
from player
Join team on player.full_name=team.player1
Where team.team_id = 8
and week =9
UNION
Select points
FROM player 
JOIN team on player.full_name=team.player2 
Where team.team_id = 8
and week =9
UNION
Select points
FROM player 
JOIN team on player.full_name=team.player3
Where team.team_id = 8
and week =9
UNION
Select points
FROM player 
JOIN team on player.full_name=team.player4
Where team.team_id = 8
and week =9
```

Any ideas on why this is occurring or a better potential way to complete this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does the column `points` belong to table `player` or `team`?

Comment: It’s in the player table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems incomplete, and you must use `UNION ALL` to get the full total (f 2 or more players have the same points `UNION DISTINCT` would eliminate those rows):

```
SELECT
    SUM( points )
FROM (
    SELECT
        points
    FROM player
    JOIN team ON player.full_name = team.player1
    WHERE team.team_id = 8
    AND week = 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        points
    FROM player
    JOIN team ON player.full_name = team.player2
    WHERE team.team_id = 8
    AND week = 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        points
    FROM player
    JOIN team ON player.full_name = team.player3
    WHERE team.team_id = 8
    AND week = 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        points
    FROM player
    JOIN team ON player.full_name = team.player4
    WHERE team.team_id = 8
) d
```

but I believe your team table needs alteration to achieve better efficiency

Please note that using `UNION` = `UNION DISTINCT` i.e. "distinct" is assumed if omitted.

This might be more efficient:

```
SELECT
    SUM( player.points )
FROM player
WHERE player.full_name IN (
    SELECT distinct
        case when cj.n = 1 then team.player1
             when cj.n = 2 then team.player2
             when cj.n = 3 then team.player3
             when cj.n = 4 then team.player4
        end
    FROM team
    cross join (
       select 1 as n union all
       select 2 as n union all
       select 3 as n union all
       select 4 as n
       ) cj
    WHERE team.team_id = 8
    )
AND player.week = 9    ;
```

Comment: Awesome that works. Thank you. I agree the team table isn’t constructed very well. I’m going to revise that but this will at least provide some functionality in the meantime

Comment: sorry, still thinking this through.

Comment: Week isn’t in team currently, but I could very easily add it at this point, and likely should it seems

Comment: OK, I have attempted a second query that "unpivots" the player names from team, so that you can filter on name simply. It might be more efficient. In future you should prefix all column references with table names (or aliases if used).